# Why this JSON value not accessible in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

JSON return by the request

```
{
    "get_image_details": [{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "one",
        "image_url": "'http:\/\/salimarts.com\/uploads\/dsc_3100.jpg'",
        "main_category_id": "1",
        "sub_category_id": "2",
        "added_by": "",
        "tags": "",
        "date_of_insert": "2018-04-02 14:15:43",
        "date_of_update": "2018-04-02 14:15:43",
        "main_category_name": "wedding",
        "sub_category1_name": "marwari"
    }]
}
```

Jquery/Ajax to get JSON

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controllers/PhotoGalleryController/get_image_details",
    type:'POST',
    datatype:'json',
    data:{'image_id':image_id},
    success: function(data)
    {
        var myObj=data;

        var imgTitle = myObj.get_image_details[0]['title'];
        alert(imgTitle);
        console.log(data);

        /*$("#mod").show();*/
        /*$(".modal-content").html(data);*/
    }
});
```

I tried this JSON in w3schools.com editor, where I can able to access but on localhost, I face this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

why this happens please tell if anyone faces this kind of issue

Comment: But in the code you have shared, you haven't accessed id property.

Comment: The code you posted does not make reference to the "id" property of anything.

Comment: sorry it's not 'id' its title

Comment: `title` is not an array index, its an object property. Try `myObj.get_image_details[0].title`

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I think you can still access object property with `[]`

Comment: Your code is correct, clearly the response isn't as you've posted at least once

Comment: Voting to close. Minimum code for reproducing the issue should be posted in the question.

Comment: because php isn't returning what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this ,it's should be working fine

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>admin_controllers/PhotoGalleryController/get_image_details",
    type:'POST',
    datatype:'json',
    data:{'image_id':image_id},
    success: function(data)
    {
        var myObj=data;

        var imgTitle = myObj.get_image_details[0].title;
        alert(imgTitle);
        console.log(data);

        /*$("#mod").show();*/
        /*$(".modal-content").html(data);*/
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

This error clearly indicates the object on which you are trying to access "title" property is undefined. Check if the ajax call is returning the expected result.

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing this answer and welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer only says what the problem is but not giving an actual solution. If you could detail HOW they would check ajax is returning what is expected or diagnosis steps that would make this a better answer. Thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: Thanks @WilliamPatton for your feedback.